# Mongo db find document from reference document id in embed many document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i want to find document jobs.transcoder._id

i have tried

```
{jobs.transcoder._id: ObjectId("552554e4d672487c358b459c")}

{ jobs: { $elemMatch: { "transcoder._id": ObjectId("552554e4d672487c358b459c") } } }
```

but don't result

my document is here

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55256f53d67248493f8b4660"),
    "jobs" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("55256f96d6724899408b459e"), 
            "transcoder" : DBRef("transcoder", ObjectId("552554e4d672487c358b459c"), "api")
        }
    ]
}
```

can i this query ?
should i use transcoderId instead of transcoder reference

Comment: your document not a valid `json` document

Comment: Your document seems to have an `array` of objects as `jobs`'s value, so maybe `jobs[0].transcode._id`?

Comment: i have tried jobs[0].transcoder._id but don't result

Comment: how to valid json document @yogesh ?

Comment: @SemihSari when I inserting your given document in mongo it shows error for this ` DBRef("transcoder"`

Comment: do not think like that. this is a sample.

Comment: there are two collection (asset, transcoder)

transcoder collection rereferenced in asset collection.

Comment: transcoder collection

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("552554e4d672487c358b459c")
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find by the document `_id`, run;

```
{"_id":ObjectId("55256f53d67248493f8b4660")}
```

If you wish to find by `jobs._id`, run;

```
{"jobs._id":ObjectId("55256f96d6724899408b459e")}
```

I assume `DBRef` acts the same as [this](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/db_ref.html) and returns a `dbref` on a lookup. If that case, you can run;

```
{"jobs.transcoder.$id": ObjectId("552554e4d672487c358b459c")}
```

Comment: yes it works.

{"jobs.transcoder.$id": ObjectId("552554e4d672487c358b459c")}

Comment: Glad to hear you've got a solution `:)`